# retrieve information using a composite variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to retrieve information using a composite variable with the following lines, but it is not working. The error report is further below, and the suppose output is at the bottom. I thank you in advance for any advise.

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE       
  TYPE type_shopper IS RECORD(
    shopperid bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE,
    firstname bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE,
    lastname bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE,
    email bb_shopper.email%TYPE);
    rec_shopper type_shopper;
    lv_days_num NUMBER(1);
    lv_shopper_num NUMBER(3) :=30;
BEGIN
  SELECT idshopper, firstname, lastname, email
    INTO rec_shopper
  FROM bb_shopper
  WHERE idshopper = lv_shopper_num
  lv_days_num := SYSDATE - rec_shopper.created;
  lv_days_num := SYSDATE - rec_shopper.created;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_shopper.firstname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_shopper.lastname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_shopper.email);
END;
/
```

The error report is the following.

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 15, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

This is suppose to be the output.

```
Shopper ID: 37
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Became shopper 1 days ago
```

Comment: Are you missing a semi colon at the end of your select query?

Comment: Thank you Aakash. I am reading examples from a book and I don't see that semi colon in the book or from my notes. In any case I added it and still does not work.

Comment: Try removing parts of the query and try to execute it, that might help.

Comment: I have tried removing, modifying, adding, changing, etc. that is why I am asking for help now. I am just learning this stuff my friend. I appreciate any help.